# SVG animation works when style is set programmatically but not when only using a stylesheet

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I have a svg document which contains a stylesheet. Using the stylesheet I can set the fill of a rect (The stylesheet is working). What I'm trying to do is to set a color changing animation. I have the following stylesheet:

```
@keyframes blinking-effect {
    0% {
        stroke: rgba(255, 255, 0, 1);
        fill: rgba(0, 220, 0, 1);
    }
    100% {
        stroke: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
        fill: rgba(0, 0, 220, 1);
    }
}
.animation {
    animation-name: "blinking-effect";
    animation-duration: "0.5s";
    animation-iteration-count: "infinite";
    animation-timing-function: "ease-in-out";
    animation-direction: "alternate";
}


<rect id="rect1" x="0" y="0" width="50%" y="50%" class="animation " />
```

I do not know why this doesn't work. However it does work when I execute the following code:

```
document.getElementById("rect1").style.setProperty("animation-name", "blinking-effect");
document.getElementById("rect1").style.setProperty("animation-duration", "0.5s");
document.getElementById("rect1").style.setProperty("animation-iteration-count", "infinite");
document.getElementById("rect1").style.setProperty("animation-timing-function", "ease-in-out");
document.getElementById("rect1").style.setProperty("animation-direction", "alternate");
```

Is there a way to do this without using JavaScript?

Comment: I can't seem to get the JavaScript working in jsFiddle

Comment: Just make the SVG. The goal is to do it without JS.

Comment: It's here: http://jsfiddle.net/j9ks4ch8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lose the quotes on the CSS.

```
.animation {
    animation-name: blinking-effect;
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-direction: alternate;
}
```

Also by the by the rect has repeated y attributes and no width which I assume is a typo and the animation class attribute ends in a space which I assume is another typo.

Answer (score 1):

Do it this way.

```css
.animate {
  -webkit-animation: blinkingEffect 0.5s infinite ease-in-out alternate;
  animation: blinkingEffect 0.5s infinite ease-in-out alternate;
}
@-webkit-keyframes blinkingEffect {
  0% {
    stroke: rgba(255, 255, 0, 1);
    fill: rgba(0, 220, 0, 1);
  }
  100% {
    stroke: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    fill: rgba(0, 0, 220, 1);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes blinkingEffect {
  0% {
    stroke: rgba(255, 255, 0, 1);
    fill: rgba(0, 220, 0, 1);
  }
  100% {
    stroke: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    fill: rgba(0, 0, 220, 1);
  }
}
@keyframes blinkingEffect {
  0% {
    stroke: rgba(255, 255, 0, 1);
    fill: rgba(0, 220, 0, 1);
  }
  100% {
    stroke: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    fill: rgba(0, 0, 220, 1);
  }
}
```

```html
<svg width="50" height="50" viewBox="-1 0 51 51">
  <rect class="animate" id="rect1" x="0" y="0" width="50" height="50" />
</svg>
```

Comment: The goal is to remove JavaScript from the equasion